# What Python library / API would you recommend for basic on-screen image and text processing?

Tags: windows, python, image-processing, computer-vision

I am building an application that interacts with my business's websites, as well as will hopefully manage some of the internal emailing as well. The emailing part is the tricky one; for the rest, I could easily go with a Selenium- or Scrapy-based solution (and actually chose and implemented that part already in Selenium without much hassle) but for the email folder it is not possible (Gmail doesn't allow it, independently whether I change the user agent or not).

Essentially what I would like to achieve is for the software to "see" where certain subfolders/labels within the business email folder and certain links in the messages themselves are located and hence to "know" where to click to navigate further. One line of simplified actions is this:

1. selecting Inbox (or any other sub-) folder
2. opening emails one-by-one
3. finding the content of the email & links in it (if any)
4. clicking on any link that has certain patterns (i.e. that are pointing to my business's sites) --> from this on, it's all done in Selenium already.
   I am aware that an OCR-type solution might be very slow. That's something I would like to avoid.

My thought was that maybe there are certain APIs or libraries that could be integrated with Python to identify simple patterns such as a large, connected light grey area in the middle (list of emails), a wide but short darker grey rectangle on top (search bar), a long narrow blue line (underline for a URL in a message).

How would you go about this? Thank you so much for your help!